# ObjectOutputStream wont write to text file despite not throwing any exceptions

Tags: java, file-writing, objectoutputstream

I want to write an object I have created to a text file, `Members.txt`, but I can't seem to get it to write and there are no exceptions. The Object class implements Serializable.

I have tried adding Objects to an `Arraylist` then writing the `Arraylist` to file, and also tried writing the Object directly.

```
Client client = new Client(name, age, email, phoneNum);

//test object 
System.out.print(client.toString());

/*write new obj to txt file*/
String filename = "Members.txt";

File file = new File(filename);

List < Client > obj;
obj = new ArrayList < Client > ();

obj.add(new Client(name, age, email, phoneNum));
obj.add(new Client(name, age, email, phoneNum));

try {
    //INCLUDES BOTH attempts
    //Attempt 1(Direct writing)

    boolean openToAppend = true;
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, openToAppend));
    out.writeObject(client);
    out.close();

    //Attempt 2 (using arraylist)

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Members.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(obj);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Print Successful");

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Should work. Look for your file in different directory. Maybe you set current dir to something else.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())`, and you'll know the actual file path of the file you're writing to. Note that naming the file "Members.txt" is weird, since Java serialization doesn't produce readable text, but binary.

Comment: _but I cant seem to get it to write_ How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: There are only two obvious things slightly wrong: A) dont name your file .txt ... when you serialize objects this way, you get **binary** data, not text! B) there is no need to close *both* output streams. As soon as you do `out.close()`, your fileOut should be closed to. Beyond that, read about try-with-resources. Beyond that, I agree: this should work, so what makes you think it does not?

Comment: Another tip: `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`, so if your handling for both these exceptions is identical, you can remove the `catch (FileNotFoundException)`

Comment: So what is the *question* here?

Comment: 1. Your second `FileOutputStream` doesn't append, so it overwrites the file created by the first one. 2. You can't append to an `ObjectOutputStream` without special provisions. 3. '`ObjectOutputStream` won't write to a text file': I agree. Serialized data is not text, and should not be saved in a 'text file', or with a `.txt` extension. 4. You are writing objects, not printing.